# Docker Container for Azure with Poweshell ExchangeOnlineManagement module

Tags: powershell, docker, exchangewebservices

I am very new to containers and trying out Docker for the first time

I want to create a Docker Image which has PowerShell 5.1 installed along with PowershellGet and ExchangeOnlineManagement modules.

I am really lost as how to use a base image and update it with the modules needed above.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first pull and run the image. https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-powershell?tab=description

Start container interactively and see if it fulfills your needs:
`docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell`

If you want to create a customized Docker Image you need to create a `Dockerfile`.

And you can use it as base image and built you image on top of https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-powershell?tab=description:

```
# Indicates image that will be used as the base image.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell

...
# add your docker instructions e.g:
RUN powershell New-Item c:\test
...
```

Afterwards in the same directory in which you have your Dockerfile: `docker build -t <username>/<image_name>:<tag_name> .`